# Why INSUFFICIENT_OUTPUT_AMOUNT?

Tags: transactions, etherscan

[image]

I sent this transaction with 74 GWEI and 185421 gas limit. So far my calculations: 74 * 185421 -> about 6.6 USD, at the time of writing.

The screenshot above shows 1.04 USD. Below it says gas used ~15%.

What's going on? Why does the transaction stop at 15% of the limit (if I understand this correctly)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error-message `INSUFFICIENT_OUTPUT_AMOUNT` is thrown from the contract function, not from the transaction.

It therefore has nothing to do with your gas-limit and gas-price configuration, and it most certainly has nothing to do with ETH/USD price.

This error-message tells you that the output amount is smaller than the minimum that you've requested for (in the `amountOutMin` input parameter which you have passed to this function).

You can observe all of this in [the contract source code on GitHub](https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-periphery/blob/master/contracts/UniswapV2Router02.sol).

Comment: Ah okay, lol, I was very mistaken. So I've to increase the slippage.

Comment: My problem was actually that I wasn't using `JSBI.toNumber` on the amount returned by uniswap to convert it to an actual number, so it was sending a ridiculously high amount. It makes sense to switch to Typescript. JS is too dangerous for this.

Comment: @Ixx: Never use `toNumber` on anything returned from a web3 call without asserting first that it is not larger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`.

Comment: For example, `if (retVal.lte(new BN(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER))) ...`.

Comment: More generally, I would recommend to avoid even that suggestion, and use only `BN` objects throughout your code. That is, unless it is designated for display purpose, in which case, you can and should use `toString()`.

Comment: BN is what's returned from the Uniswap SDK? If it is, this is what I was using first (calling raw on it), but I can't pass that to the web3 transaction, because it expects a plain number. Probably missing something, not at the computer right now.